# jQuery toggleClass not changing font-size for decedant selector with font-size set

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the font-size of all elements under a single div using jQuery click events to toggle a set class. The paragraphs under the div are targetted using a decendant selector that changes their font-size to small already. When I add in the jQuery to toggleClass for the main div only the headers change size and the decendant targetted paragraphs keep their original size. Can someone please explain this behavior to me and provide a work around or a best practice I may not be utlizing.

I've tried adding the "size" class using decendent selector in jQuery and though the paragraphs get the "size" class they still have font-size of small.

The HTML

```
<div class="middle">
  <h1>Header test</h1>
  <p>Paragraph test</p>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.middle p { font-size: small; }
.size { font-size: 5em; }
```

The jQuery for adding class

```
$('.middle').click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('size');
});
```

Fiddle to illustrate problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/e0gjLhsm/

Fiddle with class toggled by decendant

https://jsfiddle.net/2qorozg8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). For the `p` element the rule `.middle p` is more specific than the inheritance of properties from the parent `.middle` element

```
.middle p {
    font-size: small;
}
.size {
    font-size: 5em;
}
.middle.size p {
    font-size: 5em;
}
```

then

```
$('.middle').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('size');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/b07wxtez/)